# php while loop failing inexplicably while fetching result rows

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having a very strange issue and am not quite sure what to think about it...

I have a standard database query doing a select on a table. It returns a resource, num_rows = 101, and it will fetch rows up to row 42 at which point it simply stops all script execution, no errors, not timing out (takes less than a sec to get the 42 rows) ... I can't provide a link but here's the code in question...

```
$select2 = "SELECT * FROM `$dbname`.`$file" . "_settings` WHERE `weight` <> 0 ORDER BY `count` ASC";
$result = mysql_query($select2);
$lpcnt = 0;
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    /* This will print out 42 times */
    echo '<pre>In The LOOP, row('.$lpcnt.'):<br>NumRows: '.$numrows.'<br>';
    print_r($display);
    echo '</pre><br/>';
    $domRows[] = $display;
    $aTotal[] = $display['count'];
    $aTotWeight[] = $display['weight'];
    //debug vars
    $d['url'] = $display['url'];
    $d['total'] = $total;
    $d['count'] = $display['count'];
    $d['weight'] = $display['weight'];
    $dbug['domRows'][] = $d;
    $lpcnt++;
}
/* Never Reaches this */
echo '<pre>';die(print_r('Loop Finished'));
```

At a loss as to what's causing the failure midway through the results loop...

also..I know, I know...myql_ is depreciated, but's that's what I have to work with!

Thanks in advance for any light anyone can shed...this is really hurting the site!

EDIT: also this doesn't break all the time, so far it seems to be related somehow to the number of results...for example, if I run through a result set that has 39 rows, it will proccess all of them...and it's consitently failing at 42 rows... on my tables that have 100+ records

EDIT FINAL: Ok figured it out! Turns out we had our memory limit to low, so it was trying to allocate an illegal amount of memory! So we upped it and now it works! Also I had my error reporting in a spot where it was being conditionally turned back off by other code...that's why I wasn't seeing errors! Duh... anyway, thanks for the stabs, to those that responded Merry x-mas and all that jazz...

Comment: You've got `error_reporting` on, right?

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *depre*-oh wait.  Okay, now that we have that out of the way -- the `die` at the end is nonsensical.  `print_r` provides output, so passing it to `die` is silly.  If you want to exit, use `exit` *after* printing.

Comment: Are the all the array's $d, $dbug, $domRows, $aTotal, etc... declared as array's.  Also is  $dbug['domRows'] an array?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display error so you can see the actual error.

Comment: @ChristianVarga yes error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: @Charles - that's not what's breaking it never reaches the die...I'm not here to get coding advice unless it's breaking what I'm doing...which it's not..

Comment: @Ray - not pre-declared well $dbug is but not $d...and it will run through the results and print 42 of them to screen but then it just quits.. also see my response to christian regarding error_reporting..

Comment: @Ray - also I tried printing the vars at the end of the loop instead of where the current print_r is and they are all getting filled just fine...

Comment: I have something in mind but i'm not sure at all. just try it if you like and tell me what the output is:
at the end of the while loop just empty the $display array. and then let me know if it's working